# Ignore optional suffix without preceding delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I would like to capture the first part of a word, ignoring the optional suffix. Both the suffix and preceding text are composed of the same class of characters (that is, there is no delimiter before the suffix).

My first try only captures the first letter:

```
m = re.search(r'([A-Za-z]+?)(?:Suff)?', 'textSuff')
m.groups()
>>> ('t',)
```

I want to capture "text" only, but when I make the first group element greedy, it grabs the entire string.

```
m = re.search(r'([A-Za-z]+)(?:Suff)?', 'textSuff')
m.groups()
>>> ('textSuff',)
```

Is it feasible without a different character to delimit the suffix?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Barely beat me to it. This should be an answer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the suffix is optional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pattern is all constructed from optional patterns, be sure you will get as few characters in return as possible. Thus, there must be at least a boundary. I guess the word boundary `\b` is a valid way to go here (since you need to match *words*):

```
([A-Za-z]+?)(?:Suff)?\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sT4aD7/3)

[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/pCpTpO):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'([A-Za-z]+?)(?:Suff)?\b')
test_str = "textSuff more words tSuff"
print(re.findall(p, test_str))
```

Outputs:

```
['text', 'more', 'words', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that after everything either the string must end or there must be a non-acceptable character....

```
m = re.search(r'([A-Za-z]+?)(?:Suff)?(?:[^A-Za-z]|$)'
```